# The method deposit(double) is undefined for the type Double

Tags: java, types

in class BankAccount:

```
public double deposit(double PlusAmount) {
       balance += PlusAmount;
       return balance;
```

in Main class

```
    double PlusAmount = Double.parseDouble(dispFieldText);
 double MinAmount = Double.parseDouble(dispFieldText2);

  ba.balance.deposit(PlusAmount);
  ba.balance.withdraw(MinAmount);
```

i've tried to change double -> Double but it did't help.
Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to call `deposit` on `ba.balance` which is of type `Double`.

Assuming `ba` is of type `BankAccount`, you should call the methods like this:

```
ba.deposit(PlusAmount);
ba.withdraw(MinAmount);
```